# Kubernetes OpenStack integration

Tags: openstack, kubernetes

Trying to make integration work, but have some problems. When `--cloudprovider=openstack`, `kube-apiserver` is crashing immediately after start with this [message](http://pastebin.com/S9JYgMr7)
All needed configuration is provided via `cloud.conf` and loaded via `--cloudconfig=/etc/cloud.conf`.
Does anyone have success with such setup?

Error message:

```
Aug 21 15:58:00 k8s-master-01 kube-apiserver[29112]: panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
Aug 21 15:58:00 k8s-master-01 kube-apiserver[29112]: [signal 0xb code=0x1 addr=0x0 pc=0x7f43bd]
Aug 21 15:58:00 k8s-master-01 kube-apiserver[29112]: goroutine 1 [running]:
Aug 21 15:58:00 k8s-master-01 kube-apiserver[29112]: k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/cloudprovider/providers/openstack.(*OpenStack).Instances(0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x6)
Aug 21 15:58:00 k8s-master-01 kube-apiserver[29112]: /builddir/build/BUILD/kubernetes-b5a4a548df0cffb99bdcc3b9b9e48d4025d0541c/_output/local/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/cloudprovider/providers/openstack/openstack.go:163 +0x8ed
Aug 21 15:58:00 k8s-master-01 kube-apiserver[29112]: k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kube-apiserver/app.(*APIServer).Run(0xc82029b500, 0xc8202b6400, 0x0, 0x10, 0x0, 0x0)
Aug 21 15:58:00 k8s-master-01 kube-apiserver[29112]: /builddir/build/BUILD/kubernetes-b5a4a548df0cffb99bdcc3b9b9e48d4025d0541c/_output/local/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kube-apiserver/app/server.go:384 +0x1439
Aug 21 15:58:00 k8s-master-01 kube-apiserver[29112]: main.main()
Aug 21 15:58:00 k8s-master-01 kube-apiserver[29112]: /builddir/build/BUILD/kubernetes-b5a4a548df0cffb99bdcc3b9b9e48d4025d0541c/_output/local/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/cmd/kube-apiserver/apiserver.go:48 +0x171
Aug 21 15:58:00 k8s-master-01 kube-apiserver[29112]: goroutine 17 [chan receive]:
Aug 21 15:58:00 k8s-master-01 kube-apiserver[29112]: github.com/golang/glog.(*loggingT).flushDaemon(0x1d27440)
Aug 21 15:58:00 k8s-master-01 kube-apiserver[29112]: /builddir/build/BUILD/kubernetes-b5a4a548df0cffb99bdcc3b9b9e48d4025d0541c/Godeps/_workspace/src/github.com/golang/glog/glog.go:879 +0x67
Aug 21 15:58:00 k8s-master-01 kube-apiserver[29112]: created by github.com/golang/glog.init.1
Aug 21 15:58:00 k8s-master-01 kube-apiserver[29112]: /builddir/build/BUILD/kubernetes-b5a4a548df0cffb99bdcc3b9b9e48d4025d0541c/Godeps/_workspace/src/github.com/golang/glog/glog.go:410 +0x297
Aug 21 15:58:00 k8s-master-01 kube-apiserver[29112]: goroutine 24 [syscall]:
Aug 21 15:58:00 k8s-master-01 kube-apiserver[29112]: os/signal.loop()
Aug 21 15:58:00 k8s-master-01 kube-apiserver[29112]: /usr/lib/golang/src/os/signal/signal_unix.go:22 +0x18
Aug 21 15:58:00 k8s-master-01 kube-apiserver[29112]: created by os/signal.init.1
Aug 21 15:58:00 k8s-master-01 kube-apiserver[29112]: /usr/lib/golang/src/os/signal/signal_unix.go:28 +0x37
Aug 21 15:58:00 k8s-master-01 kube-apiserver[29112]: goroutine 26 [runnable]:
```

/etc/cloud.conf

```
[Global]
auth-url = OS_AUTH_URL
user-id = OS_USERNAME
api-key = OS_PASSWORD
tenant-id = OS_TENANT_ID
tenant-name = OS_TENANT_NAME
[LoadBalancer]
subnet-id = 11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111
```

Comment: Please include the error message in your question (because if the pastebin expires, this question will no longer be useful to anyone else).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Allright, `region` in mandatory option. When it's empty code will fail. You must specify it, even if your OpenStack doesn't uses regions. The biggest issue is that code itself don't checking parameters specified by user and thus cannot inform what you are doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Can you paste your cloud.conf here ? Looks like your openstack cloud did not get instantiated.

Comment: Added to question body. Here is how looks my cloud.conf.

Comment: You need to have them pointing to actual services, if you don't the cloud provider will fail to initialize.

Comment: Did you mean real values? Like real URL, username and pass? If yes - sure they are real in config, i cleaned them to show config itself. With given creds populated via env vars i can use openstack cli (python-novaclinet, etc.) Does config looks good? Maybe i missed something?